# Container stuck during boot after updating to .NET 8

Tags: c#, azure, docker, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

After successfully updating the application (ASP.NET Core) to .NET 8 and running it locally (no docker container), I am struggling to use the container in Azure.

The container won't boot. It gets stuck at a specific point in time (see logs) with no further information. This also happens when I start the container locally.

Anyone ever experienced that? I can't seem to find a solution for it.

The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-bookworm-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
COPY publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["./Application"]
```

The log provided by azure through scm:

```
2023-12-05T14:45:05.036017766Z [14:45:04 Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository
2023-12-05T14:45:05.037320672Z Storing keys in a directory '/root/ASP.NET/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed. For more information go to https://aka.ms/aspnet/dataprotectionwarning
2023-12-05T14:45:05.037338772Z 
2023-12-05T14:45:05.315275542Z [14:45:05 Warning] Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager
2023-12-05T14:45:05.315355042Z No XML encryptor configured. Key {a052ec83-e17e-4d70-8bcf-2537c7492700} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
2023-12-05T14:45:05.315362542Z 
2023-12-05T14:45:05.382496649Z [14:45:05 Information] Application.Worker.CatalogChangedMessageProcessor
2023-12-05T14:45:05.382566849Z Refreshing catalog data
2023-12-05T14:45:05.382574549Z 
2023-12-05T14:45:08.077826368Z [14:45:08 Warning] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation
2023-12-05T14:45:08.079457876Z The property 'OemCustomer.ClientApplicationIds' is a collection or enumeration type with a value converter but with no value comparer. Set a value comparer to ensure the collection/enumeration elements are compared correctly.
2023-12-05T14:45:08.079477476Z 
2023-12-05T14:45:14.160127997Z [14:45:14 Information] Application.Worker.CatalogChangedMessageProcessor
2023-12-05T14:45:14.160225699Z Refreshed catalog data
2023-12-05T14:45:14.160235499Z
```

Comment: I can see that you EXPOSE port 80. .NET 8 ASP.NET containers listen on port 8080 by default. That's a change from .NET 7 containers that listened on port 80. I doubt that's your issue, though.

Comment: Sadly not the issue, expose != ports available. Was already on .NET 7 before as well with no issue. Thanks for the headsup though, will look into it.

Comment: Hi @HansKilian your solution actually made me figure it out. By default Azure App Services try to ping docker containers on port 80. Setting 'WEBSITES_PORT' to 8080 fixes the issue. If you want, please add it as an answer, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that now by default with .NET 8, ASP.NET Core apps in docker containers, are listening on port `8080`. So changing or setting `WEBSITES_PORT` to `8080` on the app-service itself, fixed the issue.

By default an azure app-service tries to ping the docker-container using port 80.

Comment: But did you change the `EXPOSE 80` in the dockerfile?

Comment: I did for the sake of documentation. Nevertheless the default Azure app service setting would try port 80 anyway, without changing it, it would fail, no matter what I expose. You don't need to expose a port for it to be reachable.

Comment: This answer worked for me... why does Microsoft do this! ahhh wasted so much time trying to work this out. Voted Up